# How to cut the end of line in a QGIS style?

Tags: qgis, style, linestring

I want to create a style in QGIS, in which one line is offset from the other, but their ends form one point (as in the picture). How do can you remove the ends of the green line?

In QGIS 3.2 there is an EXTEND function that extends the ends, but does not shorten them...

[image: QGIS properties popup]

Comment: it is not clear to me what style you want to achieve, only something that isn't correct.  can you add a sketch of the style you want?

Answer (score 5):

You could to use style "Geometry Generator" and use this expression

difference( $geometry, buffer(  end_point(  $geometry ), 1) )

[image]